# I have a three columns section but the sections do not cover the full width of the page. How can I make the cover it?

Tags: team-sites, layouts

I think this is a Teams site and I have a section that is a three column layout
How can I force these three columns to cover the entire width of the page (screen)

Comment: I hope you are asking about three section and each section will accumulate full width of page.

Comment: I meant three columns layout, fixed the typo, thank you

Answer (score 0):

- By default, SharePoint Framework client-side web parts can't be placed in full-width column layouts. To allow users to add your web part to full-width columns, in the web part manifest (the ***.manifest.json** file next to the web part ***.ts** file)** set the supportsFullBleed property to true.

```
{
  //...

  "requiresCustomScript": false,
  "supportsFullBleed": true,

  "preconfiguredEntries": [{
    //...
  }]
}
```

- for more details refer this Microsoft docs

  [Enable support for the full-width column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/use-web-parts-full-width-column#enable-support-for-the-full-width-column)

Comment: Thank you ..that is too bad because I do not have admin level access I am just a regular user